# How to deal with null values in F#

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying to fetch data(type:double) from MS access below. There are number of null values stored in A&B below. is there a way to change those null values to zeros?

```
let query sql w= 
seq{
let conn = new OleDbConnection( @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=Portfolio.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;" )
conn.Open()
let DAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql,conn)
let DTable = new DataSet()
let i= DAdapter.Fill(DTable)
let rowCol = DTable.Tables.[0].Rows
let rowCount = rowCol.Count
for i in 0 .. (rowCount - 1) do
           yield w (rowCol.[i]) 
       }
type Table1= {  
                    A:double;
                    B:double} 



let cf=query "SELECT * FROM T" (fun row -> 
      {  
         A=unbox(row.["A"]);
         B=unbox(row.["B"]);})
```

Answer (score 4):

Define a function

```
let toFloat = function
    | null -> 0.0
    | obj -> unbox obj
```

And then use it as follows

```
let cf = query "SELECT * FROM T" (fun row -> 
      {  A = toFloat row.["A"]
         B = toFloat row.["B"] } )
```

Comment: i see this error in | value -> value "The type 'float' does not have 'null' as a proper value"

Comment: See the edited answer: Null matching must be done before unboxing.

Comment: i am still facing an error .System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. The problem is in line | obj -> unbox obj

Comment: What is the type of the columns in your sql? Maybe you need a decimal or single instead? If you _really really_ want a float, you could try System.Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof<float>). (

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, your columns in DB have different type (for example, int and double). Or try check return value with DBNull type:

```
let toDouble x = 
    if System.Convert.IsDBNull(x) then 0.0
    else System.Double.Parse(x.ToString())
```

To check I create that table:

[image]

And with your code:

```
open System.Data
open System.Data.OleDb

let toDouble x = 
    if System.Convert.IsDBNull(x) then 0.0
    else System.Double.Parse(x.ToString())

let query sql w= 
    seq{
        let conn = new OleDbConnection( @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                    Data Source=F:/Portfolio.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;" )
        conn.Open()
        let DAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql,conn)
        let DTable = new DataSet()
        let i = DAdapter.Fill(DTable)
        let rowCol = DTable.Tables.[0].Rows
        let rowCount = rowCol.Count
        for i in 0 .. (rowCount - 1) do
                yield w (rowCol.[i]) 
        conn.Close()
       }

type Table1= {  A:double; B:double } 

let cf = query "SELECT * FROM T" (fun row -> {  A = toDouble row.["A"]; B = toDouble row.["B"] } )

cf |> Seq.iter(fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
```

Result:

```
{A = 1.0;
 B = 2.2;}
{A = 3.0;
 B = 0.0;}
{A = 4.0;
 B = 0.0;}
```